# How to call modules in lib folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails just in case the question sounds stupid, I have a module in my lib folder, but how can I make calls to my module methods in a controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails 2.x lib directory was automatically included in the application’s load path. As of Rails 3, this isn't case, but you can edit this in config/application.rb to avoid the "require 'foo'" thing:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a class `Foo` in a file in your `lib` folder, simply use `Foo.method` where `method` is the (static) method you want to call.

(But don't forget to have `require 'foo'` in your controller file.)

Comment: Can I add the require in my application controller so that the method can be called from any controller?

Comment: Yes, you can require it there instead.

Comment: Or you can require it in an initializer file in your application's config/initializers folder.