# Getting Uninitialized Constant when trying to add a route for Rack application in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

Trying to add a route for Rack class as follows:

```
  match '/sms' => MsgReceiver
```

the Rack class is:

```
# /lib/msg_receiver.rb
class MsgReceiver

  def self.call(env)
    [200, {}, "test"]
    # render
  end
end
```

The error I'm getting:

```
uninitialized constant MsgReceiver (NameError)
```

Why am I getting the error, Do I have to define MsgReceiver anywhere?

Comment: I think, you have to create MsgReceiver controller, no?

Comment: Is the lib folder in your autoload paths?

Comment: @Jimmy isn't this done by default? if not how to add it?. @kinshie I think with Rack it works differently, no need for controller

Comment: @Jimmy I found out it's not done by defauly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643447/how-to-call-modules-in-lib-folder - to load it I added: config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib) put the answer below to mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://yehudakatz.com/2009/12/26/the-rails-3-router-rack-it-up/, it appears that you need...

```
match '/sms', :to => MsgReceiver
```

Based on the error message you're getting, however, I'm not sure if this will actually resolve the problem.  Perhaps, you also need to add `require 'msg_receiver'` at the top of your routes file?